# Accessing secrets in Azure ARM templates

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault

I followed tutorial on [official documention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/key-vault-parameter) how to access key vault secrets in arm templates. I tried both approaches with static and dynamic key vault id's, and I got them both working.
What is strange is for dynamic id approach amount of boilerplate(requires nested template) that needs to be set-up.

In static id approach, you need to specify this in template parameter file:

```
"adminPassword": {
        "reference": {
          "keyVault": {
          "id": "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<rg-name>/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/<vault-name>"
          },
          "secretName": "ExamplePassword"
        }
      }
```

And that is nice and simple settings.

But if I try similar settings(without nested template) for dynamic id approach in parameter section of main template file(not in parameter file) it does not work:

```
"adminPassword": {
      "type": "secureobject",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Key vault secret"
      },
      "defaultValue": {
        "reference": {
          "keyVault": {
            "id": "[resourceId('keyvault-resource-group','Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', 'keyvault-name')]"
          },
          "secretName": "ExamplePassword"
        }
      }
    }
```

Question is why this approach does not work? Maybe something to do with arm template life cycle?
This would significantly reduce amount of boilerplate when you only need to access one or two secrets from key vault.

Just to repeat I did make static and dynamic id's approach from official documentation work with nested template. This was attempt to reduce, if possible, number of lines in arm template or to remove need for nested template.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/key-vault-parameter?tabs=azure-cli#reference-secrets-with-dynamic-id), you can only declare a dynamic key vault ID in a linked template parameter, which will have to be repeated each time for each linked template.

From my understanding, you want to pass in the parameter once, then reuse it for multiple linked templates.

With the above in mind, you can pass a `securestring` from PowerShell using an inline parameter for [`New-AzResourceGroupDeployment`](https://www.bing.com/search?q=New-AzResourceGroupDeployment&cvid=8cca1e96ecaa4e768e3cd4243be0e13d&pglt=43&FORM=ANNAB1&PC=U531)

**ARM template**

```json
"adminPassword": {
  "type": "securestring",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "Key vault secret"
  }
}
```

**PowerShell**

```
$adminPassword = (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret `
    -VaultName "keyVaultName" `
    -Name "adminPassword").SecretValue

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
    -ResourceGroupName "my-resource-group" `
    -TemplateFile template.json `
    -TemplateParameterFile parameters.json `
    -adminPassword $adminPassword
```

You could also integrate this with a [Azure Key Vault Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault) in Azure Devops YAML pipelines:

```yaml
- task: AzureKeyVault@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(subscriptionID)
    KeyVaultName: $(keyVaultName)
    SecretsFilter: '*'
    RunAsPreJob: false
```

Then you can reference the secret in subsequent tasks. You could also pass this secret as a parameter to the [Azure Resource Group Deployment task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops).

Comment: I already go thru steps you suggested(https://devkimchi.com/2019/04/24/6-ways-passing-secrets-to-arm-templates). I'm trying solution(template) to be self contained as possible. And yes, I want to fetch secret and reuse it in template,without repeating that step in nested(or linked) template. Plus every resource that uses that secret needs to be moved to nested(linked) template and adds mess to 'dependsOn' dependencies. In template parameters it is possible to use functions, that is why I assumed that is also possible to reference key vault secret.

Comment: @ZnasMe I don't understand what you mean by *self contained*. Are you not using powershell to run the ARM templates to begin with? Or are you simply running the template in a Devops task? Why not just do the above and make your life simpler? My solution will keep your ARM template quite simple, since it ensures your password can be reusable throughout your whole template.

Comment: Also https://jan-v.nl/post/using-dynamically-linked-azure-key-vault-secrets-in-your-arm-template/ suggests what your trying to do is impossible.

Comment: I'm using DevOps tasks. I do not like idea that password is in clear text when you assign it in powershell. Like I said it was assumption, and only want it to know why it does not work. Maybe can somebody responsible for arm templates in MS to think to to support this feature in future.

Comment: @ZnasMe You don't need to have it as plaintext. You could use `Get-AzKeyVaultSecret` to fetch secret as a `securestring` and pass that to ARM template, as I've updated above. I'm honestly surprised what your trying doesn't work, maybe raise a support case or do a feature request to https://feedback.azure.com/. Doesn't seem like a supported usecase atm for ARM.

Comment: Another option is to just use the key vault task, then pass the secret to the ARM template task.

Comment: First, thanks for willingness and patient. What I mean by self contained in this context, that arm template should have minimal dependency on environment set-up. Because when you need to manage a lot of pipelines, it is not just one power script or task that needs to be changed later.

Comment: I think why my approach does not work have to do with arm template life cycle. Probably somebody with diaper knowledge can confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "it's not supported" - the longer answer or the reason why has to do with security, we don't want the deployment engine (that processes defaultValues) to have blanket access to everyone's key vault (and the ARM token is not the same as a KV token).  We're looking at improving the scenario but no ETA for that just yet...